# Remove Duplicate Records IDENT field -Shapefile using GDAL OGRINFO or OGR2OGR

Tags: shapefile, gdal, ogrinfo

I have two shapefiles that I am merging/combining. However, this produces more than 4,000 duplicate records.  I need to have only unique records.  Is this possible with OGRINFO or OGR2OGR?   I've tried Select DISTINCT but it only lets me do select statement on one column/field.  I can get a list of unique records but I need to create new shapefil.

Answer (score 3):

There should be no problem in using many attributes in DISTINCT query at least with the SQLite SQL dialect. Test with ogrinfo:

```
ogrinfo -dialect sqlite -sql "select distinct geometry, attribute_1, attribute_2 from my_shapefile" my_shapefile.shp
```

Comment: This works for `ogrinfo`, but not `ogr2ogr` as the questioner requires.

Comment: Works for me with ogr2ogr and gives the same result - as many features written into output file than what gets selected with ogrinfo.

Answer (score 1):

I'm trying to do the same thing, I see in the [OGR SQL](http://www.gdal.org/ogr_sql.html) documentation,

> The result of a SELECT with a DISTINCT keyword is a layer with one column (named the same as the field operated on), and one feature per distinct value. Geometries are discarded.

Why they made this choice boggles my mind. But I can confirm that

```
ogr2ogr -dialect -sqlite -sql "select distinct LINK_ID from layer" out.shp layer.shp
```

Returns only the `out.dbf` file, which contains the unique `LINK_ID` values.

Comment: SQLite dialect does not select geometry field automatically. Have you tried `select distinct geometry, LINK_ID from layer`? BTW. it does not help to read the OGR SQL manual if you use the SQLite SQL, read http://www.gdal.org/ogr_sql_sqlite.html instead. I have not tried conversion with ogr2ogr myself so you can be right, please tell if it works or not with explicitly selected geometry.

Comment: @gregmacfarlanane, have you made a test with select geometry,link_id or do you want me to build a test set?